# codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to submit my first app to the app store. When I compile (configuration set as 'Distribution') I get the error below:

> CodeSign
>   build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxxx.app
>   cd /Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxxx
>   setenv
>   IGNORE_CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_RADAR_7181968
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>   setenv PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone
>   Distribution: XXXXXXXXXX"
>   --resource-rules=/Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/Legginit/build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxxxxx.app/Entitlements.plist
>   --entitlements /Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxxxx/build/xxxxxx.build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxxxxx.build/xxxxxx.xcent
>   /Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxxx/build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxxxxx.app
>
> /Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxxx/build/Distribution-iphoneos/xxxxxx.app:
>   invalid resource selection rule(s)
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with
>   exit code 1

I've double checked the following:

1) Code Signing Identity is set to 'Any iPhone OS Device' and on the right hand side my Distrbution certificate.

2) I've created Entitlements.plist unchecked get-task-allow.

3) Bundle Identifier matches my Distribution Provisioning Profile.

4) Keychain Access has two certificates, 'iPhone Developer' and 'iPhone Distribution'.

There are plenty of threads with people receiving this error, but I've been looking at them all morning and I don't see anything different from what I have done.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Stephen

Comment: have you added the Entitlements.plist and unchecked the get-task-allow flag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved, I created a new projected and copied all the my classes over. It compiled cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem.... I resolved it by creating a new publish settings profile and reconfiguring all my build settings there.