# Problems testing iPad app on device

Tags: ipad

I'm writting an iPad app and having problems testing it on a device.
It runs fine in the simulator but as soon as I select to run on a device I get this error:

> CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/DrivingInstructorAids.app
>   cd /Users/tanderson/Documents/DrivingInstructorAids
>   setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   setenv _CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
>   /usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Developer: Matt Saunders (F56A93HGSV)" --resource-rules=/Users/tanderson/Documents/DrivingInstructorAids/build/Debug-iphoneos/DrivingInstructorAids.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/tanderson/Documents/DrivingInstructorAids/build/DrivingInstructorAids.build/Debug-iphoneos/DrivingInstructorAids.build/DrivingInstructorAids.xcent /Users/tanderson/Documents/DrivingInstructorAids/build/Debug-iphoneos/DrivingInstructorAids.app
>   /Users/tanderson/Documents/DrivingInstructorAids/build/Debug-iphoneos/DrivingInstructorAids.app: The operation was cancelled by the user.
>   Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

I've managed to install a provisioning profile with a certificate for the device by following the apple provisioning assistant. I'm not sure if its 100% correct as the whole process is extremely confusing and I'm a beginner with developing on Macs.

Could anyone give me a few pointers about what the problem might be and what to do about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of existing questions which could help you - [/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090288/usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1) and [Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)