# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, code-signing, app-store-connect

I have no idea why does this error appear when doing the final run for distribution before submitting to the iTunesConnect:

```
/Users/Val/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mathematics-dzakmzlewrmgvibasvuixiwmkwwp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mathematics.app: replacing invalid existing signature
/Users/Val/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mathematics-dzakmzlewrmgvibasvuixiwmkwwp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Mathematics.app: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

All of my certificates/profiles were made 2 minutes ago.
I read from another question that I should remove unneeded spaces from info.plist but there are no such!
I should note that I am running Xcode 4.1, reinstalled today.

Comment: This thread is old but might be of some help:  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1630090?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Setting Trust for your certificates to system default may help.  http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/76785-codesign-error-cssmerr_tp_not_trusted-codesign-failed-exit-code-1-a.html

Comment: I did set it right but the problem still persists :/

Comment: have you followed the steps provided in the Distribution section of your Apple's Account?

Comment: yes! even recreated everything today!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Yes, open Keychain.app & the Distribution Certificate, change the trust to "use system  default.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single answer to this problem, partly because Apple's error message(s) is/are not terribly specific.

For my case the solution was this:

Open this Perl script:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/PackageApplication
```

and insert this line near the top, like right after the "my $xxxx" declarations:

```
$ENV{CODESIGN_ALLOCATE} = '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate';
```

Credit to http://loopingrecursion.com/index.php?t=codesign for this answer.

The problem seemed to arise after installing some XCode 4.2 beta 7. I eventually uninstalled that one and reinstalled 4.1 from scratch but still couldn't Validate or Share, until I employed this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it using just `Build Active Architecture Only` option in the project info.