# Stuck with "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 " Error

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xcode3.2, codesign

I am getting the following error in all my the projects after I installed xcode 4.2 in parallel with  xcode 3.2.5 I get the error when I  create an  adhoc  bundle for the Tester.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

I have gone through following blogs but can't find any solution.

1. [Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)
2. http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9370-codesign-failed-exit-code-1-a.html
3. http://blog.emmerinc.be/index.php/2009/03/26/codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1/
4. [/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1090288/730776)

Comment: What was the problem? missing key? would probably make this question/answer a lot better if you could provide some information.

Comment: i could not find  exact issue but I just have cleared  all keys from key chain and all the provisioning profile from organizer and than install everything again and started working well

Comment: found following use-full  link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this error when I manually built and signed an iOS application bundle using a Makefile. In that case my `Info.plist` was missing the `CFBundleResourceSpecification` key (should probably have the value `ResourceRules.plist`). I did some more testing now and it also happens if the key `CFBundleExecutable` is missing.

`CFBundleResourceSpecification` should be added in some build phase by Xcode but maybe it's a good idea to check the resulting `Info.plist` in the build directory if it's really there.

Maybe this blog post could help, it's about `codesign` finding the wrong `Info.plist` file (one without `CFBundleResourceSpecification`)
http://infinite-sushi.com/2010/08/the-case-of-the-missing-cfbundleresourcespecification/