# code sign error Command/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

When I was submitting app on apple app store then this error occurred.

**Error**:

> code sign error Command/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

We have tried with 
[first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017756/command-usr-bin-codesign-failed-with-exit-code-1)
keychain access password reset and identifier changed and also tried to refresh certificate but not seen View Details view button.

Also tried few more other solutions like deleting old certificate and try with new certificate.

> I am using Xcode 9.4.1 OS Sierra 10.13.6

We have release several apps before. after Xcode update i am having this issue.

Comment: Hi, did you try to delete your derived data and build again?

Comment: yes  i had tried. it doesn't work

Comment: if you tried all those that you mentioned, then i think the problem might be regarding valid bundle identifiers. also, double check your code sign identity if it matches your provisioning profile